# Is there a way to hook into the update-core page for custom messages?

Tags: admin, updates, notices

We have some sites where we note a few things that need to be checked or done either before or immediately after a core, theme or plugin upgrade. While I keep a list of these things, sometimes users themselves do the upgrade and mess everything up.

I was hoping to be able to add a message to the upgrade screen to remind myself of the checklist of to do's before/after upgrade and also to warn users to contact me etc.

I'm thinking if there is a hook to let me add this customized message that'd be great. If not any suggestions how to approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an action, `'core_upgrade_preamble'`, which can be added to output anything you would like at the bottom of the upgrade-core page. For example, try:

```
add_action('core_upgrade_preamble', 'add_custom_upgrade_core_message');
function add_custom_upgrade_core_message(){
    echo "<p>HI THERE</p>";
}
```

That should work to meet your needs.